# Getting Error While Debugging the Plugin in dynamics crm 2013

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, c#-3.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm getting below error while debugging the plugin.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8013141A).

It is a CRM 2013 online instance.

Comment: Was this code previously working in CRM Online or is it new code? Does it run successfully in a local test/dev environment? Have you tried removing all CRM references from your solution, adding them back from the latest CRM 2013 SDK, and recompiling the code?

Comment: yes. i tried what you said. but its getting same error

Comment: Why are you referencing `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow` in a Plugin?

Comment: i'm not referencing that namespace. while i'm click on startexecution its getting that error. for that only i referencing that namespace but same error exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check what version of `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow` library you have referenced in your project. According to the error message, CRM is looking for the `Version=6.0.0.0`.